# how to play video in asp.net with thumbnail support?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

friends,

i am using asp.net 2.0 
my requirement is  when form is loaded it should show thumbnail of video in that control first and then on play button click streaming should start.

any one guide me is this possible or not ?
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up this problem by using youtubescript library.
youtube provide video gallery script for asp.net and other languages as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Windows Media Player activex control for the job. Take a look at it [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/scottlysle/csharpwebvideo04212007133218pm/csharpwebvideo.aspx).
Another alternative is the use of Silverlight.